# wordpress text field data -- html markup is stripped

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress wp-editor in the admin dashboard to input some text to a custom table in mySQL (column type is 'text'). It's not a normal Custom Post Type; just a separate small table in the WP mySQL. I'm currently updating the table using standard $wpdb->update -- HOWEVER, all html coding is being stripped during the update.

Does anyone know how to prepare the text data from wp-editor for $wpdb->update so it allows HTML coding (like links & in-line styles)? (while also treating punctuation properly, like stripslashes_deep )?

Comment: Have you tried this function `$your_data = stripslashes_deep($_POST['your_data'])` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep on the variable which contains html? Then pass `$your_data` to $wpdb->update.

Comment: Thanks, @user3714582 -- Tried that... it helps with a small part of the problem. It protects a few punctuation marks (like ' or " or `), but it does not solve for preserving the HTML coding during an update. Thank you.

Comment: Found a solution: it turns out there was a "filter_var($_POST['xyz'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)" hidden in another included php file that was doing the filtering before $wpdb->update even got the array. $wpdb->update doesn't do massive sanitizing after all. Thanks for your suggestion, tho, @user3714582